# The Joy of Hexasect

Tags: mathematics, geometry

This geometric construction challenge is
a set of components to be placed in order,
$\begingroup
  \def \s      #1{{ \small\sf #1 }}
   \def \AB      {         \overline {\s{AB}} }
    \def \line #1{{  \small \overleftrightarrow {\s{#1}} }}
$
dividing line segment $\AB$ of length **6**
into 6 subsegments, each of length **1**.

*hexasect* – transitive
verb – to divide into 6 equal parts

*How can $\AB$ be hexasected by placing 5 circles and 7 lines
that produce just 1 lines-only node?*

[image]

**Construction guidelines**

•
Circles and lines are placed sequentially,
in any order that accords with *nodes* that exist at times of placement.

•
A circle may be placed where a node exists for the circle’s center.

•
A line may be placed where it crosses at least two existing nodes.

•
*Nodes* are endpoints **A** and **B** as well as
intersections among circles, lines and/or $\AB$.

•
A *lines-only node* is an intersection of *lines* in the completed solution.
No circles pass through a lines-only node.
(Nodes along $\AB$ are ineligible because $\AB$
is technically a *segment*, not a *line*.)

**Example**

 *quadrisect* – transitive
verb – to divide into 4 equal parts

 A different $\AB$, of length 4, can be quadrisected
by placing 4 circles and 6 lines
that produce just 1 lines-only node.

[image]

•      Step 1
places circles centered at nodes **A** and **B**.
These circles’ intersections produce nodes **C** and **D**.

•  Step 2
places line $\line{BC}$ and a circle centered at **C**,
whose intersection produces node **E**,
and places $\line{CD}$,
whose intersection with $\AB$ produces node **F**.

•  Step 3
places a circle centered at **E**.
This circle’s intersection with $\line{BC}$
produces node **G**.

•  Step 4
places lines $\line{AD}$ and $\line{FG}$,
whose intersection produces node **H**.

•  Step 5
completes this quadrisection
by placing lines $\line{CH}$ and $\line{DG}$.
The desired lines-only node is **H**.

$\endgroup$

Comment: This quadrisection example is indeed suboptimal (and more complex than the puzzle's solution, which is tied for optimal hexasection). Optimal quadrisection uses fewer components but doesn't demonstrate a lines-only node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I believe:

> [image]

This is the easiest to understand I could find.